# Uploading a .xls file.

Tags: php

Here is my code:

```
<?php

require_once 'Excel/reader.php';

$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$_FILES["file"]["name"]);

$data->read($_FILES["file"]["name"]);


error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

echo "<table border='1'>";

echo "<tr><th>First Name</th><th>Middle Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Email ID</th></tr>";

for ($j = 1; $j <= $data->sheets[0]['numCols']; $j++)
         {
echo "<tr>";


echo "<td>";

        echo $data->sheets[0]['cells'][$j+1][1];

echo "</td>";   

echo "<td>";    

        echo $data->sheets[0]['cells'][$j+1][2];

echo "</td>";


echo "<td>";


        echo $data->sheets[0]['cells'][$j+1][3];

echo "</td>";


echo "<td>";


        echo $data->sheets[0]['cells'][$j+1][4];

echo "</td>";

        //echo "<br>";


echo "</tr>";

        }


echo "</table>";


?>
```

This running fine on localhost, but when I try to run it on the server it shows:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(Book1.xls) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/wingsele/public_html/get.php on line 6

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/tmp/phpufQkcr' to 'Book1.xls' in /home/wingsele/public_html/get.php on line 6

The filename Book1.xls is not readable
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Please fix your code: Paste it again so there are no empty lines, and use the `code` button to indent it properly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set write permissions (chmod, probably using your FTP client) to the directory you're moving the uploaded file to.

Also, in this line:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

you should specify a full path as the second parameter, e.g.

```
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],dirname(__FILE__)."/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

for the current directory.

Comment: The OP shouldn't even be using `$_FILES["file"]["name"]` and instead create a new name.

Comment: where sud i set my permisson?